# Multiple day online swiss tournament

Tags: tournament, online-chess, lichess, websites, chess.com

I want to organize a 6 round swiss tournament for 100+ players with 3 rounds/day.
I know there are websites which allow us to organize swiss tournaments
ex :- chess.com,lichess.org.
I want to know if there are websites which allow the swiss tournament to go on for many days.

Comment: Can you give an example of the sort of website you are talking about? Have you found such websites that do put a limit on the length of time they can be used for?

Comment: @JamesMartin in chess.com when I try to create a swiss event it only asks for the start date and time. I don't really know if manual scheduling is possible afterwards.

Comment: Ah thanks, I see, I completely misunderstood what you were looking for. I was thinking about a utility for managing a Swiss system tournament. But you actually mean a site to play the games online as well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, [Lichess Swiss tournaments](https://lichess.org/swiss) allow a tournament to last several days.
But to achieve your goal of three rounds per day you will need to set the value of *Interval between rounds* to "Manually schedule each round". In that case, rounds will not start automatically like when you set the interval to "1 day(s)", for example.

Please notice that Lichess Swiss tournaments can only be created by [team leaders](https://lichess.org/team/me), and can only be played by team members. The reason they give is that this type of tournament demand punctuality, dedication and patience from players, and these conditions are more likely to be met within a team than in global tournaments.

Also note that an odd number of rounds allows optimal color balance.